# https://youtu.be/7r7UUulUdag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to convert id into string to use in url

```
@tutorial_id = Demotutorial.where("job_id = ?", @job_id).select( "id")
@t_id = @tutorial_id.to_s
   render json: @t_id
```

Getting this error
S
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tutorial Json array

```
{"demotutorials":[{"demotutorials":{"id":50}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is work for me

```
@tutorial_id = Demotutorial.where("job_id = ?", @job_id).select( "id").first
@t_id = @tutorial_id[0].id.to_s
render json: @t_id
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two things for your problem

- if you using where the result is activerecord relation, which can
  have couple of records, you must select which row, I gave you
  sample first fow to choose first record
- @tuturial_id is a activerecord row, so you must choose which column, I gave you sample using @tutorial_id.id

below is sample code:

```
@tutorial_id = Demotutorial.where("job_id = ?", @job_id).select( "id").first
@t_id = @tutorial_id.id.to_s
render json: @t_id
```